# Is the .minecraft folder hidden on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I have a friend who is playing with me on a server we've created. Unfortunately, he is on a  Mac whereas I am on a Windows machine. I told him that I should be able to compile and send a `.minecraft` folder to him so that we can both play. Unfortunately, he can't find his .minecraft folder where it is supposed to be. Is it hidden and how can I unhide it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If your friend is running Lion or later, 10.7+, the Library folder is hidden**.

Open "Terminal" (located at /Applications/Utilities) and execute this command (shows all hidden folders and files): `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

Then in "Terminal" use this command to close your find process: `killall Finder`

Restart Finder and all hidden folders should now be visible.

Now, in Finder, click on your User folder, then Library, Then Application Support. Your Minecraft folder is listed here.

To hide hidden files/folders in Finder execute this command in Terminal (then restart Finder): `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE`

Alternatively, you can execute this command from Terminal to open your "Application Support" folder in a Finder window: `open ~/Library/Application\ Support/`

Answer (score 12):

Well, the Macs don't have a `.minecraft` folder. The Minecraft installation is located here:

```
<Startvolume>/Users/<User>/Library/Application Support/minecraft
```

The Library folder is hidden by default. If your friend is having trouble finding it, have him try these:

- Use Finder's 'Go' menu. Since Lion you have to press option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd>) for the entry to appear.
- Use Finder's 'Go to folder...' command (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and copy / paste `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`
- Snapshot 12w24a enables the 'Open texture pack folder' in 'Texture Packs' screen. Navigate from there to `/bin`, `/saves` etc.
- To unhide it, he can also type in Terminal: `chflags nohidden ~/Library`

[See here for more Minecraft Mac Help](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/649868-mac-support-101/#entry8508708)

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not hidden. It's just in an hard-to-find spot. The easiest way to find it is to just use the "Open resource pack folder" button from within Minecraft itself (located in *Options* → *Resource Packs*). On a Mac from within vanilla Minecraft, this will open `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks/`, and then you simply have to go up one folder (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>) to get to the `minecraft` folder at:

> ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/

However, if you're using a different launcher for the client (for example, if your server is FTB or Technic, the client files are stored elsewhere so that vanilla Minecraft is left intact and unmodded), the `minecraft` folder will be in a different location, so you can't simply go directly to `~/Library/Application Support/` and expect to find it.

Using the texture pack button will always get you to the correct folder for whichever client you're using no matter whether it's modded or not, so it's the most reliable method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly advise against showing all hidden files but you can run this `chflags nohidden ~/Library/` in the Terminal and it will make your "Library" folder (for your user only) visible. You can then follow the directions indicated by other answers (e.g. navigating to `Library -> Application Support -> Minecraft` from your home directory).

PS: You can hide your Library folder again by running `chflags hidden ~/Library`... not that you'd want to do that though!
PPS: For the most part, I use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to quickly jump to locations like that. It even does auto-complete (start typing and hit tab). If that's the only "inaccessible" folder you navigate to, you'll be glad to know OS X keeps the last used command there so you can just hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> and you're there. :)