# Where is my minecraft folder hidden in this unusual Mac setup?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

What I usually do is just open the texture-packs folder and then I have access to everything. But my Minecraft crashed, and now I can't get on without it crashing. I've been trying to find the "Error Report" in `users/library/application support/minecraft` but there are two things wrong:

1. Thing that is different is that my library folder is in the shared folder.
2. Is that correct? Even when I do get into application support, Minecraft isn't in it. And I have no idea where else it could be.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate on careful reading): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115943/is-the-minecraft-folder-hidden-on-a-mac

Comment: Suggestion: when you get it working, bookmark your texture folder.

Comment: There are two Library folders: one for your user (`/Users/[yourname]/Library`), one for your system (`/Library`). Minecraft normally puts it in the Application Support folder in the user's Library. Have you looked in both?

Answer (score 5):

Point finder to the Hard drive the install is stored on (Macintosh HD is a common name) and type minecraft.jar into the search. Then right click minecraft.jar and click "Show enclosing folder" and you should be in ~/path/minecraft/bin

Comment: If this doesn't work, ill update it when I get home from work and can use a mac (running from memory).

Comment: Note that newer minecraft intallations version the installed .jars, for example 1.13.1 is stored in a file called 1.13.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

You can manually make it visible by executing this command via terminal: `chflags nohidden ~/Library`

Alternatively, you can Open a Finder window, click the Go Menu item and click Go to Folder, then enter into the text field `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` and click Go.