# I can't find my minecraft folder on Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I re-installed Minecraft after deleting it and now I can't find my minecraft folder to install mods on. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the .minecraft folder hidden on a Mac?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115943/4797) and/or [Where is my minecraft folder hidden in this unusual Mac setup?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/120997/4797)

Answer (score 1):

~/Library/Application Support/minecraft

The problem is that the Library folder isn't visible in Finder by default. Just google "how to make library visible mac lion."

**EDIT:** Thanks to nitro.de, you don't have to make the library folder visible, just open it via terminal `open ~/Library/Application\ Support/`

Comment: You should add how to get to the folder if you dont want to make the folder visible. Finder - goto folder - ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft. Or via terminal `open ~/Library/Application\ Support/`.

Comment: shift - command - g will bring up a go menu in finder, an item can still be invisible and it will work!