# no .minecraft folder? HELP!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So, I have been trying to get this mod and I go to resource files and I have no mine craft.jar/mods/etc files so I can't get the mod and I am really frustrated. 
By the way I use an I-mac desktop.

Comment: Which mod and which guide are you using?
By the way, minecraft.JAR is a java archive, not a folder by itself. And I can't recommend altering it unless you know what you're doing. It is more probable you are looking for the minecraft folder, but to be sure of that, I would have to see the guide.

Comment: I am downloading the mod, 'Mo' creatures' and yeah I think i meant the .minecraft folder. Also, what do you mean by guide?

Comment: @Humungus You don't edit the minecraft.jar anymore..

Comment: @Misty You question may already be answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115943/is-the-minecraft-folder-hidden-on-a-mac

Comment: I did everything on that link and my mine craft folder still won't show up.

Comment: @Misty Have you tried running minecraft?

Comment: Yes it works, but to get mods I need the .minecraft folder which has bins, mods, etc.

Comment: hellooooppoooooooooo?