# Minecraft icon is disappearing on Mac taskbar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I launch MC on my Mac, the icon, the crafting table, disappears in my taskbar. It doesn't come with any crash info. Is there a cache folder I need to delete? If so, where do I go to delete it?

Comment: Try looking [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115943/is-the-minecraft-folder-hidden-on-a-mac) For crash information...

Comment: You can always try the good old reinstall: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/guides/reinstalling-minecraft/

Answer (score 0):

This is no crash or a problem. When it pops up right click it and then click "Options" then click "Keep in Dock", then it will stay.