# DMG interuption (mac)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

Whenever I try to open the Minecraft Launcher, it always comes up with this alert...

I have attempted to trouble shoot, deleting all DMGs, but time after time it keeps on coming up with this image. I feel like the only way to fix this is to uninstall Minecraft, then reinstall it but I don't want to lose all of my stuff

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't lose any of your stuff when you uninstall/reinstall. You can copy the [Minecraft folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115943/is-the-minecraft-folder-hidden-on-a-mac) to a new location, before uninstalling, then move it back after you reinstall

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a really unofficial looking error. are you sure you downloaded this from the official site? there is, in fact, a Mac version.

regardless, though, you shouldn't lose your stuff. as Ben said in the comments above, if you're still paranoid, you can copy the folders you need from the Minecraft folder to a new one, moving it back after.